# How to ignore everything after the first character input

Tags: c++, string, user-input

I would like to get rid of everything after the first `char` of a user input.
Everything is working fine, but I'm handling edge cases and if a user types something for example 'nfff' it would cause two functions to occur, when 'n' is entered as an input and when 'f' is entered as an input. I am aware that this can be solved using `if (str[0] == 'n') { function() }`, but I'd rather not use more memory with string.
Is there a more efficient way to discard everything after the first character?

Comment: Read the first character, then [`ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) until you need to start paying attention again, at the end of the line, for example..

Comment: If your goal is to read a line of text, then this is what `std::getline` is for. That's its job. Then, if you want to look and examine only the first read character, then you are completely free to do so, at your leisure.

Comment: How do you currently get user input?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) or [getchar](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/).

For example,

```cpp
char my_char;
scanf("%c", &my_char);
```

So, this will ignore everything after the first character.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cin, std::cout
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream

int main () {
  char str[2];

  std::cout << "Enter str ";
  std::cin.get (str,2);    // get c-string
  std::cout <<str<<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Use istream::get to do the trick! Size of 2 will make sure that str is null terminated.